# What is the purpose of saved* command in a .gitignore file?

Tags: python, git, gitignore

Following the `.gitignore` file in one of my research project built in python I have noticed the `saved*` command but I couldn't relate the purpose of it from that project directory.

Here're  the commands in the `.gitignore` file:

```
*.pyc

.ipynb_checkpoints

saved*
```

Now, I could make out the first two commands but why is actually the `saved*` command used for in a certain .gitignore file?

Is it for blocking any newly created directories  and treating them as unversioned files in the project folder ??

Comment: It just means ignore any files/directories that begin with the string `saved` - maybe your project generates such files and whoever wrote this `.gitignore` didn't want those to be accidentally committed.

Comment: The lines in a gitignore are not commands, but glob patterns https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any directories OR files that have names starting with 'saved' then they would be blocked from getting versioned/included in the git repo.  The '*' is a wildcard, so it is looking for the string 'saved' with or without any characters in the name after that, and ignoring those files/paths from getting included when you run git commands.

There doesn't necessarily have to be a file or directory named that....but as wkl indicated in the comments, someone likely created a path like that to copy files to but didn't want them to get committed to the repository, so they added that to the .gitignore file.

See: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files for more info on how to use .gitignore.